# SQL - Select records without duplicate on just one field in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table 1**

---

```
| Customer_ID | Template_ID  
---------------------
| C1   |  T1   |    
| C1   |  T2   |    

---------------------
```

**Table 2**

```
---------------------
| Template_ID | Product_ID  
---------------------
| T1   |  P1   |    
| T1   |  P5   |    
| T1   |  P5   |    

| T2    |  P10   |    
| T2    |  P45   |
```

**Expected Join query result:**

```
------------------------------------------
| Customer_ID | Template_ID  | Product_ID  
------------------------------------------
| C1          |  T1          |  P1
| C1          |  T1          |  P5

| C1          |  T2          |  P10
| C1          |  T2          |  P45

.
.
```

For a template, I want to get only the unique Product_ID like above. Currently my query returns P5 twice like,

```
.
.
| C1          |  T1          |  P5
| C1          |  T1          |  P5
.
.
```

How can I handle this at the query level?

Comment: What is the primary key for your `Table2`?

Answer (score 1):

use distinct

```
  select distinct t1.*,t2.productid
  from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.Template_ID  =t2.Template_ID
```

Comment: @SyAu create fiddle not text https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7d68b9ceffc2aff1ca64b55682eb2be1

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` to eliminates duplicates. It does not apply to the first column only, but to the whole row.

For example:

```
select distinct t1.customer_id, t1.template_id, t2.product_id
from t1
join t2 on t2.template_id = t1.template_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to `GROUP BY` the field you want to be unique, so Product_ID:

```
SELECT Customer_ID,  Template_ID, Product_ID
FROM table1
JOIN table2 using ( Template_ID )
GROUP BY Product_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT A.Customer_ID ,A.Template_ID  ,B.Product_ID   
FROM 
    table1 AS A
INNER JOIN table2 AS B
ON A.Template_ID   = B.Template_ID
```